# Unable to cast object in WPF XAML

Tags: c#, wpf, xaml

I am trying to bind to a WebBrowser component from the context of a TextBox.

Even though successful in Debugging, XamlDesign returns Error as InvalidCastException.
Could someone help me solve this?

My WPF project is based on the sample project (https://www.codeproject.com/Articles/1097390/Displaying-HTML-in-a-WPF-RichTextBox)
and the downloaded project also returns the same Error.

Codes in my WPF project as follows:

MainWindow.xaml

```
<Window x:Class="Wpf_HTML_display.MainWindow"
        xmlns="http://schemas.microsoft.com/winfx/2006/xaml/presentation"
        xmlns:x="http://schemas.microsoft.com/winfx/2006/xaml"
        xmlns:d="http://schemas.microsoft.com/expression/blend/2008"
        xmlns:mc="http://schemas.openxmlformats.org/markup-compatibility/2006"
        xmlns:local="clr-namespace:Wpf_HTML_display"
        mc:Ignorable="d"
        Height="1176" Width="1920" WindowState="Maximized">
<Canvas>
    <TextBox x:Name="srcHTML" Height="292" Width="1753" AcceptsReturn="True">&lt;p&gt;&lt;/p&gt;</TextBox>
    <WebBrowser x:Name="WebBrowser1" local:WebBrowserBehavior.Body="{Binding ElementName=srcHTML, Path=Text}"  Height="838" Width="1743" Canvas.Left="10" Canvas.Top="297" />
</Canvas>
</Window>
```

WebBrowserBehavior class

```
public class WebBrowserBehavior
{
    public static readonly DependencyProperty BodyProperty =
        DependencyProperty.RegisterAttached("Body", typeof(string), typeof(WebBrowserBehavior),
        new PropertyMetadata(OnChanged));

    public static string GetBody(DependencyObject dependencyObject)
    {
        return (string)dependencyObject.GetValue(BodyProperty);
    }

    public static void SetBody(DependencyObject dependencyObject, string body)
    {
        dependencyObject.SetValue(BodyProperty, body);
    }

    private static void OnChanged(DependencyObject d, DependencyPropertyChangedEventArgs e) =>
        ((WebBrowser)d).NavigateToString((string)e.NewValue);
}
```

XamlDesign returns:

```
Unable to cast object of type 'Microsoft.VisualStudio.DesignTools.WpfDesigner.InstanceBuilders.HwndHostInstance' to type 'System.Windows.Controls.WebBrowser'.
```

Answer (score 1, accepted):

This happens because a constructor OR loaded events OR `InitializeComponent` needs some data (Some basic data to load control layout. You can check in stackstrace of exeception, its all about something in `UIElement` class and generating Control to display on window) which isn't there at design time. Sometimes, Designer is not able to pass proper information about custom binding expression.

In this case, `OnChanged` gets called before `WebBrowser` is ready to handle the string OR Content.

Simple Solution is to keep `TextBox` empty initially and then assing value from code behind:

```
srcHTML.Text = @"&lt;p&gt;&lt;/p&gt;";
```

Put some validation in `OnChanged` of `WebBrowserBehavior`:

```
if (!string.IsNullOrEmpty((string)e.NewValue))
{
    ((WebBrowser)d).NavigateToString((string)e.NewValue);
}
else
{
    // CODE TO CLEAR CONTENT
}
```

In short, allow all controls to load first then perform operation.

**Tested and working.**

[image]

Comment: Yes, without validation in OnChanged of WebBrowserBehavior, I put initial HTML content into srcHTML TextBox so that it won't cause the error. Validation should have been done first. I leaned it thanks to you.